# How to understand this sentence?

Tags: image-processing

'Let V be the set of intensity values used to define adjacency. In a binary image, V = {1} if we are referring to adjacency of pixels with value 1.'
i read this sentence in Chapter 2.5 'adjacency, connectivity, regions and boundaries' of book 'digital image processing 4th edition'.Gonzalez.
i just don't understand this sentence.is it means that, if a pixel's value is 1, then V = {1}.Is V determined by the value of the pixel?pixel's intensity value can just be one certain integer, and so do V, then why V is called a 'set' rather than an integer?
how to correctly understand this sentence?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to programming. Maybe you could try asking this on https://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

**1st case:**

```
When V={1}
```

It simply means 2 neighbouring pixels should have value 1 to be considered as connected.

**Example:** V={1} and  4-connectivity:

[image]

**2nd case:**

```
When V={20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30}
```

It means 2 neighbouring pixels should have any of these values to be considered as connected.

**Example:** V = {2,3,5} and  4-connectivity:

[image]

In this picture, there is no 4-connectivity between two pixels (they are marked as gray, both have 3 value). However there is 8-connectivity. See:

[image]